# Double For Loop Not Increasing

Tags: excel, vba

I just can't seem to get this for loop running correctly. I know that I missing something basic, but I just can't figure it.

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 : (Table starts at row 7, and columns i to q are hidden)

[image]

Table 2 :

[image]

My goal is to pull new rows from Table1 to Table2.
My code rolls through Table 1, identifies the rows with an 'R' value, and fills them.
Then I want to pull data from those same rows to Table2

The code that identifies and fills the 'R' value:

```
Dim iRow As Long
With Sheet12
    iRow = Application.Count(.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("KEY").DataBodyRange)
End With

'find last row with a date
Dim jRow As Long
With Sheet12
    jRow = Application.Count(.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange)
End With
'take the value from iRow and col 1, add 1, place in iRow+1,1
Dim q As Long
For q = iRow + 7 To jRow + 6
Sheet12.Cells(q, 18) = 1 + Sheet12.Cells(q - 1, 18)
Next q
```

Then this bit I'm having trouble with. My thought was try to run a double loop, where I loop through to fill each column and then each row.

```
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long

c = jRow - iRow

For b = 11 To c + 11
    For a = iRow + 7 To jRow + 6
        ws15.Cells(b, 1).Value = "Plaid-" & Sheet12.Cells(a, 8).Value & "-" & Sheet12.Cells(a, 7).Value
        ws15.Cells(b, 2).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 18).Value
        ws15.Cells(b, 3).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 3).Value
        ws15.Cells(b, 4).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 4).Value
        ws15.Cells(b, 5).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 5).Value
        ws15.Cells(b, 6).Value = 1001
        ws15.Cells(b, 7).Value = "FILL IN"
        Next a
    Next b
```

Now the above code only copies the last row from Table1 into Table2 four times.

I know I'm close, and I'm sure I'm just tired, but I can't get it right. I appreciate everyone's time.

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger show you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double loop is causing the problem. The inside loop fills in the same row 4 times. This explains why every row has the same data.

You want to iterate the rows together so you just need 1 loop. The `b` variable is not needed.

Try this code:

```
Dim a As Long
Dim c As Long

c = jRow - iRow + 7  'start row on new sheet

For a = iRow + 7 To jRow + 6  'source data rows
      ws15.Cells(c, 1).Value = "Plaid-" & Sheet12.Cells(a, 8).Value & "-" & Sheet12.Cells(a, 7).Value
      ws15.Cells(c, 2).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 18).Value
      ws15.Cells(c, 3).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 3).Value
      ws15.Cells(c, 4).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 4).Value
      ws15.Cells(c, 5).Value = Sheet12.Cells(a, 5).Value
      ws15.Cells(c, 6).Value = 1001
      ws15.Cells(c, 7).Value = "FILL IN"
      c = c + 1  'next row on new sheet
Next a
```

Comment: like a charm. I just couldn't see it. but, just to be clear, we don't need "b" as a variable, correct?